# Image upload to MYSQL using Google App Engine (Python)

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine

I am working on application where image is uploaded by user. I have to store it in to mysql database. And later display it.
I have tried following code.

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
// Lines of code here
img=self.request.get('img')
cursor.execute("UPDATE Candidate SET  profile_pic=%s ",(mdb.escape_string(img)))
// lines of code here
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

It run at localhost but when i am deploying application on server , it gives following error.

**ImportError: No module named _mysql**
Any Guideline ?

Comment: why you are using a separate DB when your web app running on top of GAE, can't google data storage and blob server fit your requirements? Where is your MySQL hosted, it may have something to do with remove access?

Comment: @spiritwalker,  I am using google cloud SQL . Because there are many requirements that doesnt allow me to use google data storage. Thats why using google cloud sql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from google.appengine.api import rdbms
conn = rdbms.connect(instance='instance_name', database='database', user='user', password='password')
```

[Using Google Cloud SQL with App Engine Python SDK](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/developers-guide)

Mysql is not Google Cloud SQL.

Expanding this answer based on the comments, for local development you use mySQL but you do it via the cloud interface provided by GAE. Then when you deploy you won't have these sorts of problems. You don't need to import MySQL at all despite the fact that's what you are really using locally.

Comment: MySQL ist not GCS, that's correct. But Google Cloud SQL is using a MySQL database and in my experience only the connection differs from a standard MySQL database. (Only for everybodys information :)

Comment: Sure, but the docs note that you should have an install of MySQL to test locally with and it seems that upon deployment it fails for the OP. So why does it fail if it's MySQL on the server side too?

Comment: The App Engine has many restrictions. One of these is to check if you have access to the Google Cloud SQL instance from your Google App Engine. The normal JDBC driver doesn't check this. And there are many more that differs between the AppEngineDriver (for Java) and the normal JDBC API. For another example the AppEngineDriver uses Googles [ApiProxy](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/apphosting/api/ApiProxy) to communicate with the cloud sql instance. But only Google knows all of the differences :) .

Comment: Sure, but what I meant really was what's the answer to the OP's question :)

Comment: As this answer states, the OP needs to use the cloud SQL method of connection in dev and in production `from google.appengine.api import rdbms`  and take into account any other differences between mysql and cloudsql. As pointed in the answer the OP probably needs to work through all of the correct authorizations etc  as per the docs provided in the link.  We can only assume that the OP hasn't done this given the information provided and they are importing mysql libs.

Comment: Paul C, the answer ist -> `_mysql` or the wrapper `MySQLdb` is using sockets to connect to the database. Sockets are not allowed in the GAE, thats the reason why the `_mysql` lib is on the blacklist of the GAE (_No module named _mysql_). The local dev server is not as strict as the GAE server. For example, you can also create folders on the dev server, which is not allowed in the GAE.

Comment: da_re, I know :) What I'm saying is that you should put that as an answer to the question asked!